# Correct way to use Nor, Neither

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence correct?

> What is this "Email" tag? It is not HTML tag, nor I could find it in the "comfy" documentation.

As you may have already noticed I am not native English speaker, so please don't judge me too harsh. You can also comment on all the sentences in this post. It would be useful to know where my weaknesses are.

Comment: You will have inversion after "nor":...nor could I find it in the...

Comment: Did you do some research about the use of "nor"? // Are you familiar with English Language Learners?  Check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its use in this case is to say "It is also not in the comfy documentation." or "I could not find it in the comfy documentation either."

The typical use would be "It is not an HTML tag, nor could I find it in the "comfy" documentation." The words *could* and *I* just needed to be reversed.